# Can we post Actions on an object outside of the app (ie FB Page, FB Place)?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

Is it at all possible to post an action (owned by the app) to an object (**NOT** owned by the app)? Specifically on Faceook Page and Places, objects owned by FB.

For example I want to create an action called "shop", so that I can create the action

"John **drank** **Coke**"

in which Coke refers to the FB Page.

I have done a test via the Graph API Explorer and it seems that the app's action POST must refer to an object also owned by the same app. Mind you, I also do not know what shud be syntax to refer to objects owned by FB.

You can tag a place to a post but it will simply prefix it with " -at Walmart"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  To set the "at Walmart" part, set the action's "place" field when creating an action via a POST.  For example, you can pass this:

```
?place=https://www.facebook.com/pages/Pizzeria-Delfina/53645450697
```

which should result in setting the place on an action like:

```
"place": {
    "location": {
        "city": "San Francisco, CA", 
        "zip": "94110", 
        "country": 398, 
        "region": 0, 
        "address": "3611 18th Street/2406 California St.", 
        "id": 2421836
    }, 
    "id": "53645450697", 
    "name": "Pizzeria Delfina"
},
```

Documentation on the basic action properties is here:

https://developers.intern.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/actions/#create

Comment: But doesn't that add it as a place?
"John shopped - at Walmart"
I actually want to do something like
"John drank Coke" - in which Coke refers to the official Coke page


My question is probably too ambiguous, have editted to make it more clearer.